# Mysql : How to add data to the existing data stored in a variable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I wish to add data to the existing variable which I created in Mysql.

```
set @variable = select * from b where b.id = 35;
```

`@variable = select * from b where b.name = "dheeraj";`

How can I go ahead with this type of query.

Comment: What do you want to add ? Your first `set` also does not make sense. Select queries would return multiple columns (and possible rows). This cannot be set into a single variable

Comment: Not possible MySQL user variables can only hold a scalar datatype like a int or string (or string formatted data like XML or JSON) data.. Not SQL tables rows and columns.. the question is what are you going to do with the variable..

Comment: I want to have set of all ids return from table b and then want have search with it in some other table;

Comment: "I want to have set of all ids return from table b and then want have search with it in some other table; " Make a temporary table instead but why not a JOIN, a JOIN sounds more suitable in this situation?

Comment: I want to have different small queries than a big query.
P.S. The actual query differs from one given above ... I've to take field from 8 different table and then have an update in some other table on basis of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @variable := (select name.* from a)  

set @variable := concat(@variable , ',' , select name.* from b)
```